# Python3 pandas - iterating on records between 2 dataframes and calculating minimal distance by column groups

Tags: python, pandas, loops, distance

I have 2 different Pandas datasets (python3) with same structure(columns: country, region, week, COL1-COL180). D1 is small ~ 300 rows, D2 with over 200k rows. 
For all the records/rows in D1 (small dataframe) I would like to iterate through the rows of the D2 dataframe, matching on country+region, and extract the record that is most similar to the record in D1. 
Similarity is determined by calculating the distance between the values in columns col1-col180. Basically distance=[sum(D1.COLi-D2.COLi)^2]where i ranges from 0 to 180. 
The record for which this distance is minimal should be selected and saved in a separate dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

What I'm going to suggest is a fairly naive brute force approach, but should be a decent start. There are quite a few ways you can optimise it:

```
def calculate_distance(row_a, row_b):
    # Calculate the distance between two rows here.

d3_rows = []

for row in d1:
    maching_rows = d2.loc[(d2.country == row.country) & (d2.region == row.region)]
    closest_row = None
    closest_distance = float('inf')
    for row2 in matching_rows:
        distance = calculate_distance(row, row2)
        if distance < closest_distance:
            closest_row = row2
            closest_distance = distance
    d3_rows.append(closest_row)

d3 = pandas.concat(d3_rows)
```

Essentially, you get the matching rows from the larger DataFrame for each of the rows in the smaller frame, and then calculate the distance for each. You don't need to keep the distances, so you simply keep whichever one has the closest distance.

What I've done here will be pretty slow, but you can speed it up with other optimizations. (E.g. how many of the rows in D1 have the same country and region?)

Comment: thanks much for the response! However something is not quite right...i keep getting an error message "ValueError: No objects to concatenate" and there are definitely row matches. I think the matching statement is not quite right. Any idea how to fix that? thank you